# Adding chart content into NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, navigationview

I'm new and followed two tutorials in order to develop my budget tracker app. One tutorial was for marking the tab bar, and the other one, for charts.

I'm trying to add the charts into the NavigationView (if I'm not wrong) so that the user can interact/see. Is there a way to add the content from the charts into my first screen, or home?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import MobileAnalyticsChartSwift


//Making the Tab Bar
struct TabItem {

}

struct ContentView: View {
@State var selectedIndex = 0
@State var presented = false

let icons = [
    "house",
    "gear",
    "plus",
    "lasso",
    "message"
]

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0){
        //Content
        ZStack {
            Spacer().fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presented, content: {
                Button(action: {
                    presented.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Close")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.pink)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                })
            })
            
            switch selectedIndex {
            case 0:
                HomeView()
                NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("First Screen")
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Home")
                }
```

and below all the other code (other cases, spacing, fonts, etc) from the tab bar, there's the charts code:

```
//Creating a ChartView and AnalyticsChartSpriteKitModuleInput using AnalyticsChartSpriteKitAssembly:
let (chartView, moduleInput) = AnalyticsChartSpriteKitAssembly.makeModule(
    inputData: chartViewModel
)

// Creating a fade animation configuration
let fadeAnimation = ChartFadeAnimation(
    fadeOutColor: UIColor(white: 219 / 255, alpha: 1),
    fadeInColor: UIColor(white: 236 / 255, alpha: 1),
    startDuration: 0.2,
    fadeOutDuration: 0.6,
    fadeInDuration: 0.6
)

// Creating date formatters
let dmmmyyyyDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
    return df
}()

let dmmmDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "d MMM "
    return df
}()

// Creating a chart data
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dates = (0 ..< 6).compactMap {
    calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: $0), to: Date())
}
let values: [CGFloat] = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
let chartData = ChartData(
    values: values,
    dates: dates
)
let path = ChartPath(
    type: .horizontalQuadratic,
    color: UIColor(red: 51 / 255, green: 102 / 255, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
    minWidth: 1.0,
    maxWidth: 5.0,
    fadeAnimation: fadeAnimation
)
let chartRenderConfiguration = ChartRenderConfiguration(
    unit: .quantity,
    path: path,
    gradient: nil
)
let analyticsChartSpriteKitViewModel = AnalyticsChartSpriteKitViewModel(
    data: chartData,
    configuration: chartRenderConfiguration
)

// Creating a range label configuration
let rangeLabel = ChartRangeLabel(
    color: UIColor(white: 102 / 255, alpha: 1),
    font: .systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular),
    dateFormatter: dmmmyyyyDateFormatter,
    insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 16, right: 0)
)

// Creating a xAxis configuration
let xAxis = ChartXAxis(
    labelColor: UIColor(white: 179 / 255, alpha: 1),
    labelFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .regular),
    dateFormatter: dmmmDateFormatter,
    insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0),
    margins: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16),
    zoomFactorLabels: 1.5
)

// Creating a yAxis configuration
let yAxis = ChartYAxis(
    labelColor: UIColor(white: 179 / 255, alpha: 1),
    labelFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .regular),
    labelInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 16, bottom: 8, right: 0),
    lineColor: UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.12),
    lineWidth: 1
)

// Creating a zero line
let zeroLine = ChartZeroLine(
    color: UIColor(white: 236 / 255, alpha: 1),
    width: 1
)

// Creating a gesture state configuration
let gestureState = ChartGestureState(
    swipeIsActive: true,
    pinchIsActive: true,
    handleIsActive: true
)

// Creating a animation configuration
let animation = ChartAnimation(
    redrawDuration: 0.2
)

// Creating a definition configuration
let definitionView = ChartDefinitionView(
    backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.043, green: 0.09, blue: 0.204, alpha: 1),
    valueLabelFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 13),
    valueLabelColor: UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0),
    dateLabelFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 11),
    dateLabelColor: UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 1.0),
    dateFormatter: dmmmyyyyDateFormatter
)
let definition = ChartDefinition(
    line: ChartDefinitionLine(color: UIColor(white: 236 / 255, alpha: 1), width: 1),
    point: ChartDefinitionPoint(minRadius: 4, maxRadius: 8),
    view: definitionView,
    fadeAnimation: fadeAnimation
)

// Creating a chart sprite kit module input data
let chartViewModel = AnalyticsChartSpriteKitModuleInputData(
    viewModels: [analyticsChartSpriteKitViewModel],
    renderConfiguration: RenderConfiguration(
        rangeLabel: rangeLabel,
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        zeroLine: zeroLine,
        gestureState: gestureState,
        animation: animation,
        definition: definition,
        backgroundColor: UIColor(white: 247 / 255, alpha: 1),
        chartInsets: .zero,
        chartMargins: UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0),
        fadeInDuration: 0.3,
        fadeOutDuration: 0.3
    ),
    calculatorConfiguration: CalculatorConfiguration(
        minStaticValue: nil,
        maxStaticValue: nil
    )
)
```

I tried various things like just putting `NavigationView()` in front of the charts code, but honestly, I have no idea what I was doing and am doing right now.

Couldn't find anything really similar to my problem on the web.

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of stuff missing here. Why is `HomeView` inside a `switch` statement? Why is there a `NavigationView` below `HomeView`? Are the charts views actual SwiftUI views or are the UIKit? You said that that second block of code is "below" the other code. Is it in a function? In the same `View`?

Comment: All this code is in ContentView.swift. Dude in the tutorial was making a `switch` statement for whenever you touched any of the icons in the tab bar. I will edit my question and provide more context to the tab bar.

Comment: Try to include a [mre]. What you have here is not clear and not enough to debug/try.

Comment: There's no problem in the code, it's just that the charts are not showing in the app, only the tab bar. I know I'm doing something wrong since they're different tutorials. In short, I dont know how to implement code from a tutorial into  another one.

Comment: `MobileAnalyticsChartSwift` looks like it's all UIKit/SpriteKit. Have you read Apple's tutorial on integrating UIKit with SwiftUI? https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit